# Upload Function in AngularJs requires to be double clicked to display table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am uploading and displaying a csv file using angular. The Upload button/function takes care of reading and parsing the csv so the html can display. However, the table is not displaying the with the initial click, it requires a second click of the upload button to display. When I log in console, it shows that the array of objects is created after the first click.

```
vm.upload = function () {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var lines = e.target.result.split("\n");
        var result = [];
        var headers = lines[0].split(',');
        for(var i = 1;i<lines.length;i++){
            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(',');

            for(var j = 0;j < headers.length; j++){
                obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];

            }
            if (obj[headers[1]] == undefined){
                continue;
            }
            result.push(obj);

        }
        vm.head = headers;
        vm.data = result;

        console.log(result);
        console.log(headers)
        console.log(vm.data)
    }
    reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
    vm.editTable = false
    vm.display = true;

};
```

Comment: Some more details would be helpful. What is `vm`? Do you expect your table to display just by setting `vm.data`? If so, have you tried doing that with the js console to see if it works? Is `readAsText` supposed to trigger `reader.onload`? If so, are you sure it does? A fiddle or similar would help here.

Answer (score 0):

Because your scope changes are not happening as a direct (i.e. non-async) result of a user interaction, you probably been to use $scope.$apply to trigger a UI update.

Jim Hoskins has a good blog post about this:

[Jim's Blog](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)